# Intersection area of circle with Vesica piscis

Tags: geometry

What is the intersection area between a circle $C_1(a_1, |a_1,a_2|)$ and a [vesica piscis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vesica_piscis) made by two points $(a_2,a_3)$, where $a_1,a_2, a_3$ are three points with polar corrdiantes $(r_1,\theta_1),(r_2,\theta_2),(r_3,\theta_3)$, respectively.

Comment: Never knew there was a name for that!

Comment: it may have an arbitrary shape!!